# can I have two different onclick methods for one button

Tags: java, android

I wanted to know if its possible to have two onclick methods for one buttton..Im trying to have a button that can open a new activity and send a id token to the server for firebase purposes, if possible how do i go about it on android studio

Comment: you can use flag for that

Comment: you mean 2 actions in same click event? or maybe first click one action and second click another? please clarify a bit and put code of what have you tried

Comment: please specify you qestion. yes you can have two onclick methods. one is called onClick and the other one is called OnLongClick. but it's not clear what you want to do.

Comment: if you want to perform two actions with one click, just add another method and call that in you onClick function

Comment: instead of having two onClick methods for single button, create two methods and call it on that button click.

Comment: ok so the activity is a register activity, after users enter their registration details they click the button which opens another activity,so what I would like for it to do is not only open another activity but also send a token to my server that will enable me to use firebase for notification purposes...hope im clear enough

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting the underlying concept wrong.

Buttons react to clicks.

The "ActionListener" that gets triggered on that click ... can do whatever it wants. There is nothing (conceptually) that prevents you in your code to just trigger various things. Of course, you have to understand what you are doing (things like: not blocking the UI thread for too long; or how to kick of things in background threads, and so on).

Answer (score 1):

No. There is only one onClick method for a Button. But you can still perform two different purposes by one button.
I am using a button to hide and show a linear layout. The code is given below :

```
final int[] count = {2};
//here startTopics is the button....
 startTopics.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(count[0] %2==0)
                {
                    topicLin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    count[0]++;
                }
                else
                {
                    topicLin.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                                  //here topicLin is the linear layout
                    count[0]++;
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks eventually your answer solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is **one** button and so you should apply only **one** onClick listener which performs the buttons job.

In your onClick-method you can just call another (private) method if you want to do multiple things without sacrificing code management.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        sendTokenToServer();
        // Include your code to open the activity here or outsource it again into another private method
    }
});
```

And your method to send the token to the server:

```
private void sendTokenToServer() {
    // Your code here.
}
```